# Intent-filter pathPattern for custom scheme

Tags: android, intentfilter

I would like my app to handle the following custom url `myscheme://product?id=123`. This is working as expected. However, the following url also is getting handled `myscheme://product/something/else?id=123` How do I prevent the second url from being handled by the app?

I setup the intent-filter that handles the deep link like following in the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

     <data android:scheme="myscheme"/>
     <data android:host="product"/>
     <data android:pathPattern=".*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I just started playing with deep linking so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the .* with .product?* this should align the filter with only the product querystring, and not the product url path (/product/something/else?id)

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

 <data android:scheme="myscheme"/>
 <data android:host="product"/>
 <data android:pathPattern=".product?*"/>
```

Another option would be to create two intent filters, and put them in order of receipt intent:

```
Intent 1: product/something/else
Intent 2: product?id=1
```

UPDATE: The key here is using getData() not get extras(). Learned that the hard way :)

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    super.onNewIntent(i);
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    if (i != null && i.getData() != null) {
    try {
            Uri data = i.getData();
            Map<String, String> a = splitQuery(data);
            if (a.containsKey("Product") && a.containsKey("SOMETHINGELSE")){
                //todo:something that takes care of something else: 
            }else if (a.containsKey("Product")){
                mItemNumber = a.get("ID");
                setUpFragmentForItem(mItemNumber);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Split URI into segments:

```
public static Map<String, String> splitQuery(Uri url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        Map<String, String> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        String query = url.getQuery();
        String[] pairs = query.split("/");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            query_pairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return query_pairs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnsupportedEncodingException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Found a library that does the same thing, worth mentioning, haven't used it, but I may give it a try:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2072

Comment: Do you mean that it did not fix the problem, or it caused the function to not work at all?

Comment: It caused the function to not work. The link `product?id=1` always leads to play store rather than being handled in the app

Comment: I feel the true problem is that the host value is "product", so it would route all "product"?id and "product"/something/else?id to this intent filter because of the host name. The other option is to handle it on the activity side within the  @Override onNewIntent(Intent intent)   and handle accordingly by decoding the URI that is passed in the intent. For completeness, try the path pattern as ".", it may cause it to ignore the rest of the URI.

Comment: Seems like handling it in the receiving activity is the way to go. I will check and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I will update the answer with an example I use myself.

Comment: That would be really helpful :)